# How do I specify login info for git for cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, bitbucket

I am trying to compile a source code directory with cmake.
Inside the CMakeLists.txt file there is the following line:

```
configure_file(DummyLibraryDependencies.txt.in DummyLibraryDependencies-download/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Here is the DummyLibraryDependencies.txt.in file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)
project(DummyLibraryDependencies-download NONE)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(DummyLibraryDependencies
   GIT_REPOSITORY    https://bitbucket.org/acme/DummyLibraryDependencies.git
   GIT_TAG           v1.2
   SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/DummyLibraryDependencies"
   BINARY_DIR        ""
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
   BUILD_COMMAND     ""
   INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
   TEST_COMMAND      ""
   GIT_PROGRESS      true
)
```

When I try to build this folder either from VS 2017 or VS 2019 or using cmake-gui
I always get prompted for bitbucket log-in info:

[image]

And when I fill in this info it somehow fails.

The message I get in cmake-gui is this:

```
Cloning into 'DummyLibraryDependencies'...

  fatal: ArgumentOutOfRangeException encountered.

     Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

  Parameter name: resultType
```

**How can I specify the bitbucket login info in some settings file so that I am not prompted with this GUI?**

NB! I have installed a bitbucket extension to VS 2017 and have not found how to uninstall it.

Comment: Hi ! Did you checked this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/651) about this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Credential Manager I had a credential for `git:https://Andy@bitbucket.org` 
I added a generic credential with same username and password as this one for `git:https://bitbucket.org`.
That solved the problem for me.